# JavaScript framework/pattern that loads or initializes components from element(s) on page

Tags: javascript

All the JS frameworks (Vue, etc) I saw until right now seems to load the data from server (AJAX) and then render it into page (mainly using a hidden DOM tree).

I wonder if there is any JS framework (or library or pattern) in which the components can be initialized with data already present on the (server side) rendered page (html).

For example I might have a ProductList component that is loading its data from server....but what if it can be somehow bind to a specific HTML element and it will loads the data from there, at least the initial state.